# Linear quadratic stochastic optimal control problem confusion with Hamilton-Jacobi Bellman equation

Tags: optimal-control, stochastic-differential-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I have the following stochastic optimal control problem, where

$$dx = u(t)dt + \sqrt{2\nu}dW(t)$$

and $x(t_0) = x_0$ and where $W(t)$ is the Wiener process/Brownian motion, and the cost function is,

$$J(x_0,t_0,u) = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{t_0}^T \frac{1}{2}\|u(\tau)\|^2 + \frac{1}{2}\|x(\tau)\|^2\, d\tau + g(x(T))  \right]$$

with $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2$. The value function is,

$$\phi(x,t) = \inf_u J(x,t,u)$$

and we have that $\phi$ solves the HJB equation,

$$ -\partial_t \phi - \nu \Delta \phi + \frac{1}{2} \|\nabla_x \phi\|^2 - \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2 = 0$$

A solution to the above HJB equation is $\phi(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2 + \nu(T-t)$. From this, the optimal control should then be $u(t) = -\nabla_x \phi$, so we *should* have,

$$ x(t) = x(t_0)e^{-(t-t_0)} + \sqrt{2\nu} W(t - t_0)$$

But if I insert the $u(t)$ and the $x(t)$ into the cost function $J(x_0, t_0, u)$, I do NOT get $\phi(x,t) = \frac{1}{2} \|x\|^2 + \nu(T-t)$. Rather, I get $\phi(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2 + \frac{\nu}{2}(T-t)^2 + \nu(T-t)$, but this doesn't solve the HJB equation.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** The above is when $x$ is 1 dimension. If $x$ is of dimension $d$ then all that needs to be changed is in $\phi(x,t)$, where instead of $\nu$ we should change to $\nu d$.

**Edit2, What I did:** For simplicity, assume $t_0=0$, and let $X(0)=x_0$. In 1 dimension, if $dX_t = -X_tdt + \sqrt{2\nu}dW_t$ then the solution for $X_t$ should be,

$$ X(t) = x_0 e^{-t} + \sqrt{2\nu} W_{t}$$

is that right? Then using that $u(t) = -x_0e^{-t}$, if I plug this into $J(x_0, t_0, u)$, I get:

\begin{align} 
J(x_0, 0, u) &= \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_{0}^T \frac{1}{2} x_0^2e^{-2t} + \frac{1}{2}\left(x_0 e^{-t} + \sqrt{2\nu} W_t \right)^2 \, dt + \frac{1}{2}\left(x_0 e^{-T} + \sqrt{2\nu} W_T \right)^2 \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_{0}^T x_0^2 e^{-2t} + x_0e^{-t}\sqrt{2\nu}W_t + \nu W_t^2\,dt \right] \\
&\qquad +\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{2}x_0^2 e^{-2T} + x_0 e^{-T}\sqrt{2\nu}W_T + \nu W_T^2 \right] \\
&= \int_0^T x_0^2 e^{-2t} +  x_0 e^{-t} \sqrt{2\nu}\mathbb{E}[W_t] + \nu \mathbb{E}[W_t^2]\,dt \\
&\qquad + \frac{1}{2}x_0^2 e^{-2T} + x_0 e^{-T}\sqrt{2\nu}\mathbb{E}[W_T] + \nu \mathbb{E}[W_T^2]
\end{align}

At this point since $\mathbb{E}[W_t] = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[W_t^2] = t$ for all $t$, then,

\begin{align}
J(x_0, 0, u) &= -\frac{1}{2}x_0^2 e^{-2T} + \frac{1}{2}x_0^2 + \frac{\nu}{2}T^2 + \frac{1}{2}x_0^2 e^{-2T} + vT \\
&= \frac{1}{2}x_0^2 + \frac{\nu}{2}T^2 + \nu T
\end{align}

So I get an extra $\frac{\nu}{2}T^2$ term. **Where did I go wrong?**

Comment: What is $\tau$ in the argument of $u$ in the definition of the cost function $J$? Was this a typo and $t$ was meant to be used or is $\tau$ perhaps a stopping time of some sort?

Comment: Oh sorry I wanted the integration dummy variable to be $\tau$. I'll edit it.

Comment: I want to take a look at this but just to be sure, what norm are you using here?

Comment: It's the standard Euclidean norm. Thank you for taking the time to look at it. Edit: But I mainly did the computations in 1D, which was enough to produce my confusion. Edit2: Oh if it is more than 1D, then everywhere you see $\nu$ you should change to $\nu d$ where $d$ is the space dimension. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Okay sorry, but just to be extra precise, if you go to higher dimensions, then you should change to $\nu d$ in the exact solution $\phi$, but not anywhere else.

Comment: I will write up an answer in much more detail I think but I wanted to comment first. I looked at $\sup_u -J(x,t,u)$ instead. In one spatial dimension, I found the optimal control for the equivalent problem, in feedback form, as $u=\phi_x$ and HJB as $\phi_t+0.5 \phi_x^2 +\nu \phi_{xx}-0.5x^2=0$ and $\phi(x,T)=-x^2/2$. This is solved by $\phi=-x^2/2-\nu(T-t)$ which gives optimal control $u=x$ where $X_t=x$ so that $dX_t=-X_t dt + \sqrt{2\nu}dW_t$. I am not sure exactly what went wrong with your attempt but it might help to try verify this approach. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thank you for writing it out. I made an Edit2 with the exact calculation that led to my confusion. Maybe after seeing that, we can see where I went wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well I found the error in my calculation. Basically, I got the solution of the SDE incorrect. If

$$ dX_t = -X_tdt + \sqrt{2\nu}dW_t$$

then the solution is

$$X(t) = X(0)e^{-t} + \sqrt{2\nu} \int_0^t e^{s-t}\,dW(s).$$

In my original question, I got the solution of the SDE wrong.